# How do I draw ellipse in opengl with mvp

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

How to draw circle/ellipse and transform it with Model-View-Projection.

I draw an ellipse in a rectangle with `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...)`.

I made a shader, It works, but how to transform it?

Vertex shader

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader

```c
#version 400 core

uniform mat4 u_mvp;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
out vec4 color;

float pow2(float x) { return x * x; }

void main()
{
    vec2 d = (gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy) * 2 - vec2(1.0);
    vec4 pos = vec4(d, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 center = vec4(0.0);

    float r = distance(pos, center);
    r = step(0.5, r);
    color = vec4(0.7f, 0.8f, 0.1f, 1.0f - r);
}
```

How to add MVP support?.

Comment: Do you wish to transform it each frame? or should it just always appear in the same position but transformed?

Comment: @HenryLeBerre In each frame. Set uniform and render. The main problem is to transform it with MVP.

Comment: Each fragment defines a ray in normalized device space. You have to transform the ray by the `inverse(u_mvp)` from normalized device space, to models (object) space.

Comment: You can draw the ellipse into a texture, big enough to be detailed. Points out of the ellipse should be transparent Then render the texture with typical MVP process.

Comment: @Rabbid76 It works for `glm::scale` and `glm::rotate`, but it ignores `glm::translate`.
I multiplied `pos` and `center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options, to achieve what you want. On of them is to create a function, which intersects a ray and sphere.
The following algorithm is taken from [Peter Shirley's](https://research.nvidia.com/person/peter-shirley) book [Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28794030-ray-tracing-in-one-weekend).
The ray is defined by an `origin` and a `direction`. The sphere is defined by a `center` point and a `radius`:

```c
float hit_sphere(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 center, float radius)
{
    vec3 oc = origin - center;
    float a = dot(direction, direction);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, direction);
    float c = dot(oc, oc) - radius*radius;
    float discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (discriminant > 0.0)
    {
        float temp = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        if (temp > 0.0)
            return 1.0;
        temp = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        if (temp > 0.0)
            return 1.0;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Compute 2 points on the ray. Each point in normalized device space with the xy coordinates `xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy * 2.0 - 1.0` is on the same ray.
`vec4(xy, -1.0, 1.0)` is on the near plane and `vec4(xy, 1.0, 1.0)` is on the far plane. Transform this points by the [`inverse`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/inverse.xhtml) model view projection matrix (`u_mvp`) and divide the `xyz` components by the `w` component to get a ray in model space in cartesian coordinates.
Size the algorithm computes 2 points on the ray, this works for perspective projection and orthographic projection.

```c
vec4 pn = inverse(u_mvp) * vec4(xy, -1.0, 1.0);
vec4 pf = inverse(u_mvp) * vec4(xy, 1.0, 1.0);

vec3 orig = pn.xyz/pn.w;
vec3 dir  = pf.xyz/pf.w - orig;
```

Use the ray to intersect the sphere in model space:

```c
vec3  center = vec3(0.0);
float radius = 1.0;
float r = hit_sphere(orig, dir, center, radius);
```

I've tested the algorithm with the view matrix `glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(0, 0, -3))` and the projection matrix `glm::perspective(glm::radians(90), aspect, 0.1, 10.0)`

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform mat4 u_mvp; 
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

float hit_sphere(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, vec3 center, float radius)
{
    vec3 oc = origin - center;
    float a = dot(direction, direction);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, direction);
    float c = dot(oc, oc) - radius*radius;
    float discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (discriminant > 0.0)
    {
        float temp = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        if (temp > 0.0)
            return 1.0;
        temp = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
        if (temp > 0.0)
            return 1.0;
    }
    return 0.0;
}

void main()
{
    vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

    vec4 pn = inverse(u_mvp) * vec4(xy, -1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 pf = inverse(u_mvp) * vec4(xy, 1.0, 1.0);

    vec3 orig = pn.xyz/pn.w;
    vec3 dir  = pf.xyz/pf.w - orig;

    vec3  center = vec3(0.0);
    float radius = 1.0;
    float r = hit_sphere(orig, dir, center, radius);

    vec4 backcolor = vec4(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
    vec4 color = vec4(0.7, 0.8, 0.1, 1.0);

    frag_color = mix(backcolor, color, r);
}
```